# Selenium Textarea error

Tags: python, selenium, bots

i'm trying to send keys in a textarea but it give me the error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
```

my code is

```
barra_commenti= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='react-root']/section/main/section/div[1]/div[1]/div/article[1]/div[2]/section[3]/form").click()
time.sleep(2)
barra_commenti.send_keys("ciao")
```

The textarea is this

```
<textarea aria-label="Aggiungi un commento..." placeholder="Aggiungi un 
commento..." class="_bilrf" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" 
style="height: 18px;"></textarea>
```

it's the instagram comment bar, i don't understand why it dosn't go
I tried too with selenium chrome extension for see if it doesn't goo on it too but it works so it's only in the program that gives the error

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
barra_commenti= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='react-. 
 root']/section/main/section/div[1]/div[1]/div/article[1]/div[2]/section[3]/form")
barra_commenti.click()
time.sleep(2)
barra_commenti.send_keys("ciao")
```

Comment: error changed `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot focus element` i'm tryng to automate comments on instagram for let u understand better

Comment: Can you replace your click with send_keys(Keys.ENTER) and make sure to import Keys: from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

Comment: tried yet but nothing. I have imported the keys from selenium becouse the don't works only in this line

Comment: It gives me `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot focus element`

Comment: Ok, what browser you are using and what's  the driver version ?

Comment: I'm using Chromedriver version  2.38.552522

Comment: Could you also try by replacing click with send_keys(u'\ue007') ?. Also I'm hoping you're using chrome browser version between 65 to 67.

Comment: i have also tried with actionchains but error  `AttributeError: 'ActionChains' object has no attribute 'sendKeys' `

Comment: yes i'm using chrome version 66, i tried too to use send_keys(u'\ue007') but nothing changes :c